# Flutter Numeric List Subtotal by category

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I intentionally do not include any code b/c there could be a number of ways to accomplish the task.

I don't want to use any packages.

My goal is to create a list with subcategories based on a text label where I could see list subtotals for each group.

I have a numeric input. Everything is saved to SQFlite database. I want to create several text labels, and I want to group each input into the corresponding category based on the label name so the list will be like this:

```
Expenses
Rent: 2000
Utility Bills: 1000 
Subtotal: 3000

Income
Mutual Funds: 200
CD: 300
Bonds: 400
Small Business: 1000
Subtotal: 1900

Total: 4900
```

Rent, Utility Bills, Mutual Funds, etc. are all input fields.

I have several issues:

1. How I do group input based on a text label?
2. What control should I use to show the Subtotal?
3. How would I calculate Subtotal for each group?
4. How do I calculate the Grand Total?

Could you please provide some ideas.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear by the question how the database is structured but the code below should produce:[image]

Data models for each income and expense

```dart
class IncomeModel {
  final int mutualFunds;
  final int cd;
  final int bonds;
  final int smallBusiness;
  final String addedTimeUtc;
  final String? updatedTimeUtc;

  IncomeModel({
    required this.mutualFunds,
    required this.cd,
    required this.bonds,
    required this.smallBusiness,
    required this.addedTimeUtc,
    this.updatedTimeUtc,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      Income.mutualFunds: mutualFunds,
      Income.cd: cd,
      Income.bonds: bonds,
      Income.smallBusiness: smallBusiness,
      Time.addedTimeUtc: addedTimeUtc,
      Time.updatedTimeUtc: updatedTimeUtc,
    };
  }

  factory IncomeModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return IncomeModel(
      mutualFunds: map[Income.mutualFunds] as int,
      cd: map[Income.cd] as int,
      bonds: map[Income.bonds] as int,
      smallBusiness: map[Income.smallBusiness] as int,
      addedTimeUtc: map[Time.addedTimeUtc] as String,
      updatedTimeUtc: map[Time.updatedTimeUtc] as String?,
    );
  }
}

class ExpenseModel {
  final int rent;
  final int utilityBills;
  final String addedTimeUtc;
  final String? updatedTimeUtc;

  ExpenseModel({
    required this.rent,
    required this.utilityBills,
    required this.addedTimeUtc,
    this.updatedTimeUtc,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      Expense.rent: rent,
      Expense.utilityBills: utilityBills,
      Time.addedTimeUtc: addedTimeUtc,
      Time.updatedTimeUtc: updatedTimeUtc,
    };
  }

  factory ExpenseModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ExpenseModel(
      rent: map[Expense.rent] as int,
      utilityBills: map[Expense.utilityBills] as int,
      addedTimeUtc: map[Time.addedTimeUtc] as String,
      updatedTimeUtc: map[Time.updatedTimeUtc] as String?,
    );
  }
}
```

Constant values for each & time. This helps avoid errors that may arise from misspells.

```dart
class Time {
  static const String addedTimeUtc = 'added_time_utc';
  static const String updatedTimeUtc = 'updated_time_utc';
}

class Income {
  static const String table = 'income';
  static const String id = 'id';
  static const String mutualFunds = 'mutual_funds';
  static const String cd = 'cd';
  static const String bonds = 'bonds';
  static const String smallBusiness = 'small_business';

  static const addTable = '''CREATE TABLE $table (
      $id INTEGER,
      $mutualFunds INTEGER,
      $cd INTEGER,
      $bonds INTEGER,
      $smallBusiness INTEGER,
      ${Time.addedTimeUtc} TEXT NOT NULL,
      ${Time.updatedTimeUtc} TEXT,
      PRIMARY KEY ($id)
    )''';
}

class Expense {
  static const String table = 'expense';
  static const String id = 'id';
  static const String rent = 'rent';
  static const String utilityBills = 'utility_bills';

  static const addTable = '''CREATE TABLE $table (
      $id INTEGER,
      $rent INTEGER,
      $utilityBills INTEGER,
      ${Time.addedTimeUtc} TEXT NOT NULL,
      ${Time.updatedTimeUtc} TEXT,
      PRIMARY KEY ($id)
    )''';
}
```

Function to initialize database. How this is done may be dependent on platform.

```dart
Future<Database> initDb() async {
  sqfliteFfiInit();
  final factory = databaseFactoryFfi;
  return await factory.openDatabase(
    'demo.db',
    options: OpenDatabaseOptions(
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (db, version) async {
        await db.transaction((txn) async {
          await txn.execute(Income.addTable);
          await txn.execute(Expense.addTable);
          await insertData(txn);
        }).catchError((e) {
          // handle error
        });
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Function to insert initial data.

```dart
insertData(Transaction txn) async {
  final income = IncomeModel(
    mutualFunds: 200,
    cd: 300,
    bonds: 400,
    smallBusiness: 1000,
    addedTimeUtc: DateTime.now().toUtc().toIso8601String(),
  );

  await txn.insert(Income.table, income.toMap());

  final expense = ExpenseModel(
    rent: 2000,
    utilityBills: 1000,
    addedTimeUtc: DateTime.now().toUtc().toIso8601String(),
  );

  await txn.insert(Expense.table, expense.toMap());
}
```

Function to query database. This returns a record which **requires at least dart language version 3.**

```dart
  Future<(IncomeModel, ExpenseModel)> queryDb() async {
    Database db = await initDb();

    late IncomeModel income;
    late ExpenseModel expense;

    return await db.transaction((txn) async {
      final incomeQ = await txn.query(Income.table);
      final expenseQ = await txn.query(Expense.table);
      income = IncomeModel.fromMap(incomeQ.first);
      expense = ExpenseModel.fromMap(expenseQ.first);
      return (income, expense);
    }).catchError((e) {
      // handle error
    });
  }
```

The widget that builds the page

```dart
class NumericListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NumericListPage({super.key});

  sumIncomeSubTotal(IncomeModel income) {
    return income.mutualFunds + income.cd + income.bonds + income.smallBusiness;
  }

  sumExpenseSubTotal(ExpenseModel expense) {
    return expense.rent + expense.utilityBills;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: queryDb(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            List<Widget> children;
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final income = snapshot.data!.$1;
              final expense = snapshot.data!.$2;

              final incomeSubtotal = sumIncomeSubTotal(income);
              final expenseSubtotal = sumExpenseSubTotal(expense);

              final total = incomeSubtotal + expenseSubtotal;

              final netIncome = incomeSubtotal - expenseSubtotal;
              children = <Widget>[
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      'Income',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Mutual Funds:'),
                      Text(
                        '${income.mutualFunds}',
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      const Text('CD:'),
                      Text(
                        '${income.cd}',
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Bonds:'),
                      Text(
                        '${income.bonds}',
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Small Business:'),
                      Text(
                        '${income.smallBusiness}',
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Text(
                      'Subtotal: $incomeSubtotal',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      'Expense',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Rent:'),
                      Text(
                        '${expense.rent}',
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Utility Bills:'),
                      Text(
                        '${expense.utilityBills}',
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Text(
                      'Subtotal: $expenseSubtotal',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Text(
                      'Net Income: $netIncome',
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ];
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              children = <Widget>[
                const Icon(
                  Icons.error_outline,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  size: 60,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                  child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
                ),
              ];
            } else {
              children = const <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                  child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
                ),
              ];
            }
            return Container(
              width: 280,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: children,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```